# Does the TB_LOADIMAGES message return a valid count?

Tags: winapi, toolbar

Here is a fragment of my program, with the last line sending a TB_LOADIMAGES message to the newly-created toolbar.

```
hWndToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, TEXT("This is the toolbar"), WS_CHILD | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS,
  0, 500, 200, 32, hWndMain, (HMENU) ID_TOOLBAR, hInstance, NULL);
if (!hWndToolbar) return false;

const int numButtons = 3;
TBBUTTON tbButtonsAdd[numButtons] = {
    {MAKELONG(HIST_BACK,0), IDM_ABOUT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR) TEXT("junk")},
    {MAKELONG(HIST_FORWARD,0), IDM_ABOUT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR) TEXT("two")},
    {MAKELONG(HIST_FAVORITES,0), IDM_ABOUT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR) TEXT("three")}
}; 

debugInt = SendMessage(hWndToolbar, TB_LOADIMAGES, (WPARAM)IDB_HIST_SMALL_COLOR, (LPARAM)HINST_COMMCTRL);
```

According to what I read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787381(v=vs.85).aspx) the return value from the SendMessage() should be the number of images in the image list, but I'm always seeing 0.  Am I misreading the documentation?  I would read the 0 as a fail.

The toolbar otherwise seems to work fine, and the images loaded are indeed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is misleading. The return value actually indicates the index of the first image added to the image list (i.e. the number of images that existed *before* the new ones were added).

So the first time you send this message (assuming you haven't previously assigned your own non-empty image list to the toolbar), `0` is the expected return for success. If you send the message again to add more images you'll see a different value returned.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I can see that the return value would be useful as a base to reference images later.